# Swift generic inheritance

Tags: swift, generics, inheritance

I have one base view controller and some child view controllers. I am having difficulty to pass the view model created in children view controller (CommentViewController) to it's parent view controller (FeedBaseViewController) to access.

```
class BaseViewController: UIViewController {
    ...
}

class FeedBaseViewController: BaseViewController {
    var viewModel1 = FeedBaseViewModel<BaseObject>()
    ...
}

class CommentViewController: FeedBaseViewController {
    var viewModel2: CommentViewModel<CommentObject>

    init() {
        viewModel2 = CommentViewModel()

        /* This is where I have issue, and I tried a few approaches. And here are the 2 of them.*/
        // Method 1:
        // viewModel1 = viewModel2
        // Error: Cannot assign value of type 'CommentViewModel<CommentObject>' to type 'FeedBaseViewModel<BaseObject>'

        // Method 2:
        // viewModel1 = viewModel2 as FeedBaseViewModel<BaseObject>
        // Error: Cannot convert value of type 'CommentViewModel<CommentObject>' to type 'FeedBaseViewModel<BaseObject>' in coercion

        ...

    }
    ...
}
```

My view models for the View Controller

```
class FeedBaseViewModel<Item: BaseObject> {
}

class CommentViewModel<T: CommentObject>: FeedBaseViewModel<CommentObject> {
}
```

Here are the object classes, the BaseObject class is the only Objective-C class here, and a CommentObject swift class which inherit from BaseObject.

```
@interface BaseObject : NSObject <NSCoding>
@end

class CommentObject: BaseObject {
}
```

I am not sure if it is possible to do, or it is only syntax issue.
Please advice, thank you!

Edited(2017-09-11):

I think I could provide more information of what I would like to achieve, and hope it helps.

`FeedBaseViewModel` stores and manipulate an array of items with type BaseObject. 
`FeedBaseViewController` have UI handling actions such as "filtering", "sorting", and ask `FeedBaseViewModel` to do the job.

For the Comment part, I will have a `CommentObject` array with basic manipulation and some specific manipulation. This is why `CommentViewModel` comes in, `CommentViewModel` inherit `FeedBaseViewModel` so that basic manipulation can be handled by the parent, and it will do the specific manipulation itself.

Similar in the view controller part, `CommentViewController` will inherit `FeedBaseViewController`, so `FeedBaseViewController` can do the basic handling while `CommentViewController` itself can provide additional functions.

Answer (score 2):

I do not think that is possible.

Your problem boils down to:

```
let m = FeedBaseViewModel<CommentObject>()
let k : FeedBaseViewModel<BaseObject> = m
```

That is not allowed. As to why: assume that `FeedBaseViewModel` contains a member of its generic type and offers a `set` function for that member. *If* you now would be allowed to write the second line, then call `set` using a `BasObject` instance that would violate the generic constraint of `m` because they are still the same object instance with different generic constraints, a `BaseObject` instance is not necessarily an instance of `CommentObject`.

A solution in your case should be to move the generics up a little bit more:

```
class FeedBaseViewController<T : BaseObject>: BaseViewController {

    var viewModel1: FeedBaseViewModel<T>

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        viewModel1 = FeedBaseViewModel<T>()
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
}

class CommentViewController: FeedBaseViewController<CommentObject> {
    var viewModel2: CommentViewModel<CommentObject>

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        viewModel2 = CommentViewModel<CommentObject>()
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
        viewModel1 = viewModel2 
        // now this assignment is allowed because viewModel1 and viewModel2 have the super type FeedBaseViewModel<CommentObject>
    }
}
```

Not sure if that solution works in your situation though.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! This is not work for me now since my CommentViewController and FeedBaseViewController may be called from Objective-C codes, Objective-C codes cannot access these classes after making such changes. I will reference to your answer and do some refactoring soon if there is no other choices.

I am still not fully understand why m cannot assign to k. In the following 2 lines of codes:

`let i = CommentObject()`

`let j: BaseObject = i`

This is acceptable, but why not for generic?

Comment: @Wilfred because generics are something different and polymorphism simply does not necessarily apply to them in the same way as it does to "regular" classes + instances. The key terms for this are "generics " + "covariance" / "contravariance" / "invariance".