# How to declare base classes in Swift's generics?

Tags: ios, swift, generics, mvvm

Example of code which doesn't work, but I would like to have it compiled with success. Idea is described very nicely in following source code. You can paste it into Swift playground easily.

```
import UIKit

// MARK: - Base classes with generics

class FlowController {

}

class ViewModel<FlowControllerType: FlowController> {
    let flowController: FlowControllerType
    init (flowController: FlowControllerType) {
        self.flowController = flowController
    }
}

class ViewController<ViewModelType: ViewModel<FlowController>> {

    var viewModel: ViewModelType!
}

// MARK: - My implementation

class MyFlowController: FlowController {

}

class MyViewModel: ViewModel<MyFlowController> {
    override init (flowController: MyFlowController) {
        super.init(flowController: flowController)
    }
}

// ERROR: 'ViewController' requires that 'MyModelView' inherit from 'ViewModel<FlowController>'
class MyViewController: ViewController<MyViewModel> {

}

// MARK: - Code

let viewController = MyViewController()
viewController.viewModel = MyViewModel(flowController: MyFlowController())
```

Problem is that I would like to declare `MyViewController`, but I get error:

```
'ViewController' requires that 'MyModelView' inherit from 'ViewModel<FlowController>'
```

Question is how to declare these classes to make it working? Should I use `where` clause for this? I want to have my own types for `ViewController.viewModel` and `ViewModel.flowController` in base classes keeping these dependencies between classes. Thank you in advance.

Related question:
[Swift generic inheritance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46112299/swift-generic-inheritance)

Answer (score 3):

I have probably answer, but it could look better than this solution. Trick is in following line

```
class ViewController<FlowControllerType: FlowController, ViewModelType: ViewModel<FlowControllerType>> {
```

which should be used instead of

```
class ViewController<ViewModelType: ViewModel<FlowController>> {
```

I hope somebody else will do it better, but for now only this works. Full playground example:

```
import UIKit

// MARK: - Base classes with generics

class FlowController {

}

class ViewModel<FlowControllerType: FlowController> {
    let flowController: FlowControllerType
    init (flowController: FlowControllerType) {
        self.flowController = flowController
    }
}

class ViewController<FlowControllerType: FlowController, ViewModelType: ViewModel<FlowControllerType>> {

    var viewModel: ViewModelType!
}

// MARK: - My implementation

class MyFlowController: FlowController {

}

class MyViewModel: ViewModel<MyFlowController> {
    override init (flowController: MyFlowController) {
        super.init(flowController: flowController)
    }
}

class MyViewController: ViewController<MyFlowController, MyViewModel> {

}

// MARK: - Code

let viewController = MyViewController()
viewController.viewModel = MyViewModel(flowController: MyFlowController())
```

Comment: Problems with this solution:
1. You cannot add easily weak reference FlowController.viewController. You need to add there some base class without generics, for example BaseViewController.
2. It won't work for Objective-C. Generic classes cannot be imported to Objective-C code.

Comment: 1. You shouldn't need to have a direct access to the view controller from the flow controller. A base class or even a protocol should be enough.